# Unable to import a self created module for python 2.6

Tags: python, import, module

Hi I am new to python and I having trouble importing a module that I created which is a in a subfolder. The folder structure is

```
installer/
    __init__.py
    initial.py
    Scripts/
       __init__.py
       script1.py
       script2.py
       myxml.xml
```

The initial.py is trying to call script1 and script 2 in the Scripts Folder using an import however every time I try to import it gives me

```
    ImportError: No module named Scripts.script1
```

My sys.path does indeed have the folder in which I am launching the script from.  I am using pydev on eclipse, I am using python 2.6 and the **_*init*_**.py has

```
    __all__=["script1","script2"]
```

Thank you for any advice you can give.

**EDIT**
The import I am trying is

```
    import Scripts.script1
```

and the contents of script1 is just parsing an xml file also in the Scripts folder

Comment: Could you please add the `import` you're trying? Also, what are the contents of `Scripts`?

Comment: the import I am trying is import Scripts.script1
the content of the scripts are just commands parse a xml file which is in the same folder as script1.py

Comment: Edit the question and add it there, please

Comment: I take that the `import Scripts.script1` is in `initial.py`? I reproduced your setup and at least, from the command line, this works: `from installer import initial` (and `initial` has imported `Scripts.script1`)

Comment: Your wrote `Script.script1` but your folder is called `Scripts`, not `Script`. Which is correct? Or is that typo the problem?

Comment: Would it make a difference if the same script was run in pydev in eclipse? I also tried on PythonWin with the same structure and code and I got the same error.

Comment: Please clarify if you use "import Script.script1" or "import Scripts.script1"

Comment: I have clarified it in the Question again I apologize for the confusion

Comment: @BrandonFung then the problem couldn't be reproduced on my machine if all typos fixed

Comment: Oh it was a typo that I overlooked thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error may occurs just because of some possible typos:

1. typo of file names, i.e., you're importing something like `srcitp1`, or, it should be `Scripts.script1` instead of `Script.script1`.
2. typo of `__init__.py`, there should be **four underscores** there, not `_init_.py` or `___init___.py`.

Comment: Indeed there are four underscores and I have checked that the imports are not typos.

Comment: @BrandonFung is `import Script.script1` another typo of `import Scripts.script1`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that `__all__` declaration. You would only use that if you actually had defined or imported the names into that `__init__` file. Since you haven't, it's likely confusing the import mechanism.

Comment: I have tried to remove the ____all____ but it still gave me error